# Growth of a function of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f:(0,\infty ) \rightarrow (0,\infty )$ be strictly decreasing function. Consider

$$
h(x) = \frac{f(\frac{x}{1+x})}{1+f(\frac{x}{1+x})}
$$

Options:

$(A)$ $h$ is strictly decreasing.
$(B)$ $h$ is strictly increasing.
$(C)$ $h$ is strictly decreasing at first and then strictly increasing.
$(D)$ $h$ is strictly increasing at first and then strictly decreasing .

My attempt:

Strictly increasing (decreasing) nature of a function depends on the derivative hence I took the derivative of $h$ using the definition provided as follows,
$$h'(x) = \frac{f'(.)}{(1+x)^2} \frac{1}{(1+f(.)))^2}
$$

Now, denominator is positive quantity and numerator is negative (as $f$ is strictly decreasing) So, we can conclude h is strictly decreasing.

Is this approach correct? any improvements would be appreciated...

Comment: Seems correct to me